# How to tell if /GS compiler is enabled for a PE Win32

Tags: c++, c, winapi, portable-executable, executable-format

I am able to parse ASLR, DEP, SEH, etc. from the DOS headers but not sure how to tell if the file was compiled with /GS stack canaries.

I am writing a program, so pointing me to a program like PEStudio won't help me unless its open source.

Is this part of the dos headers? Or do I have to scan the .data section for __security_cookie?

Comment: C or C++? Also, DOS or windows? Anyway, does the OS need to know about that detail?

Comment: Unlike ASLR, DEP, SEH, etc., /GS does not require operating system intervention. It is handled entirely within the application. Therefore, there is no need for a PE bit to indicate whether /GS is active. (Which is good, because there may be some files compiled with /GS and some without.)

Comment: I figured as much, so is parsing through the .data section the way to go?  Could get messy.  Are there any other signatures left by /GS?

Comment: Do you have access to the object files or private symbols? Some compilers will embed the command line used during compilation into those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Go to [IMAGE_NT_HEADERS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680336(v=vs.85).aspx)
- Then [IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680339(v=vs.85).aspx) (IMAGE_NT_HEADERS.OptionalHeader )
- Then [IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680305(v=vs.85).aspx) (IMAGE_NT_HEADERS.OptionalHeader.DataDirectory)
- The 10th entry VirtualAddress member is an RVA to the "Load Configuration Directory".

  - IMAGE_NT_HEADERS.OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_LOAD_CONFIG].VirtualAddress

The Load Configuration Directory is an [IMAGE_LOAD_CONFIG_DIRECTORY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680328(v=vs.85).aspx) structure.

Check the SecurityCookie member: if it's not 0 then /GS is in use for this PE.